# Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Read permission denied

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building RichText editor using Tiptap and one of my menu button has the following action on Click:

```
  async function handleHtmlPaste() {
    // editor?.chain().focus().run();
    const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
    // let text = `<h1 style="margin-left: 0px!important;">Test</h1><h2 style="margin-left: 0px!important;">Basic text formatting</h2>`;
    editor
      ?.chain()
      .focus()
      .command((props) => {
        props.view.pasteHTML(text);
        return true;
      });

    return true;
  }
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Read permission denied. What is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `navigator.clipboard.readText()` browser pops up a message like,

> Website wants to see text and images on the clipboard?

[image]

And asks the user's permission whether to **allow** or **deny**. You will get this error for 3 reasons:

1. User **denied** the access request.
2. At the OS level, The browser **doesn't** have permission to access the clipboard. (Happens mostly on **MacOS**)
3. If it is a **Chromium Extension**, You might need to add `clipboardRead` under **permissions** in `manifest.json`

Also, Check the current site permission status

[image]